# How to name files with correct alphanumerical syntax in R?

Tags: r, export, naming

I am trying to save a list of pngs of my plots, and I want the plots to be correctly alphanumerically ordered when named. Meaning, I do not want a plot named 10Plot.png to be found earlier than one named 1Plot.png. Since I am using Image Magick to make gifs from the plots, this order is important, and I would need the numbering to be three digits at all times. So, I need 1Plot.png to actually be 001Plot.png, 10Plot.png to be 010Plot.png, and so on.

Below is a minimal example just focusing on how I am currently naming the pngs:

```
plotCount <- 100 # How many plots I would like to create a name for

nameList <- list() # Empty list to just contain the names

for(i in 1:plotCount){
  nameList[i] <- paste(i, "_Plot.png", sep = "")
}
```

I am using the nameList to simply represent what I need (correctly named pngs), to avoid requiring someone to make 100 pngs on their computer.

Comment: No loops, just `sprintf("%03d_Plot.png", 1:100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is vectorized, you don't need loops.

```r
plotCount <- 100L

nameList <- sprintf("%03d_Plot.png", seq.int(plotCount))
head(nameList, 20)
#>  [1] "001_Plot.png" "002_Plot.png" "003_Plot.png" "004_Plot.png" "005_Plot.png"
#>  [6] "006_Plot.png" "007_Plot.png" "008_Plot.png" "009_Plot.png" "010_Plot.png"
#> [11] "011_Plot.png" "012_Plot.png" "013_Plot.png" "014_Plot.png" "015_Plot.png"
#> [16] "016_Plot.png" "017_Plot.png" "018_Plot.png" "019_Plot.png" "020_Plot.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

And here is a `for` loop solution, as requested in comment. Also with `sprintf`.

```r
plotCount <- 100L # How many plots I would like to create a name for
nameList <- character(plotCount) # Empty vector to just contain the names

for(i in seq.int(plotCount)){
  nameList[i] <- sprintf("%03d_Plot.png", i)
}

head(nameList, 20)
#>  [1] "001_Plot.png" "002_Plot.png" "003_Plot.png" "004_Plot.png" "005_Plot.png"
#>  [6] "006_Plot.png" "007_Plot.png" "008_Plot.png" "009_Plot.png" "010_Plot.png"
#> [11] "011_Plot.png" "012_Plot.png" "013_Plot.png" "014_Plot.png" "015_Plot.png"
#> [16] "016_Plot.png" "017_Plot.png" "018_Plot.png" "019_Plot.png" "020_Plot.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

If all that is needed is a new, consecutively numbered name, then the following might be better.

Note that I have changed `plotCount` to only `10L`, a test doesn't need to print 100 lines.

```r
plotCount <- 10L # How many plots I would like to create a name for

for(i in seq.int(plotCount)){
  png_name <- sprintf("%03d_Plot.png", i)
  # do something with this string, 
  # here I print it
  cat("This is the current PNG name:", png_name, "\n")
}
#> This is the current PNG name: 001_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 002_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 003_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 004_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 005_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 006_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 007_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 008_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 009_Plot.png 
#> This is the current PNG name: 010_Plot.png
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I understand, however my example code is a simplified version of what I am actually doing. I am making one png for every title that I create in the loop, so I can't make a list of all the names I need at once and use that. Is there a solution using loops?

Comment: @ImranS I don't understand now, do you need `nameList`? If yes, create it beforehand, then in the loop use `nameList[i]`, right? Anyway I will edit with a loop solution. Give me a sec. Done.

Comment: I don't actually need a nameList, this was just how I wanted to ask for what I needed (numbered names with three digits). I did not want to give my entire code since it would require someone to create 100 pngs on their computer for a simple question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ImranS Are you instead looking for the second edit? It creates one name only, uses  then loops. In the end you will have one extra character string only, not a vector of length `plotCount`.

Comment: Not quite, but you have given me a solution that also works, so it is fine. Thanks!